# dpkg-deb: error: archive ... has premature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up

Tags: apt, package-management

I want to install Artemis in an Ubuntu 14.04 guest machine, but I get this error.

Can anyone help me?

```
root@mah-VirtualBox:~# sudo apt-get install artemis
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-gdm-1.0 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-polkit-1.0 libass9
  libavcodec57 libavutil55 libbs2b0 libchromaprint1 libcrystalhd3 libdc1394-22
  libdca0 libde265-0 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 libegl-mesa0 libevdev2 libfaad2
  libfftw3-double3 libflite1 libfluidsynth1 libgadu3 libgdm1 libglvnd0 libgme0
  libgnome-desktop-3-17 libgrilo-0.3-0 libgsm1 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0
  libilmbase12 libinput-bin libinput10 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libkate1
  liblilv-0-0 libmjpegutils-2.1-0 libmms0 libmodplug1 libmp3lame0 libmpcdec6
  libmpeg2encpp-2.1-0 libmpg123-0 libmplex2-2.1-0 libofa0 libopenal-data
  libopenal1 libopenexr22 libopenjp2-7 libopenmpt0 libprotobuf-c1
  librhythmbox-core10 libserd-0-0 libshine3 libsndio6.1 libsord-0-0
  libsoundtouch1 libsoxr0 libspandsp2 libsratom-0-0 libsrtp2-1 libswresample2
  libtwolame0 libva-drm2 libva-x11-2 libva2 libvdpau1 libvo-aacenc0
  libvo-amrwbenc0 libvpx5 libvulkan1 libwebpdemux2 libwebpmux3
  libwebrtc-audio-processing1 libwildmidi-config libwildmidi2 libx264-152
  libx265-146 libxvidcore4 libyaml-0-2 libzbar0 libzvbi-common libzvbi0
  pidgin-data python3-cups python3-yaml
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  accountsservice adwaita-icon-theme apparmor apt apt-transport-https
  apt-utils aptdaemon autoconf automake autopoint autotools-dev
  bash-completion binfmt-support binutils binutils-common
  binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu build-essential bzip2 bzip2-doc
  ca-certificates-java cdbs cpp cpp-7 dbus debconf debhelper default-jre
  default-jre-headless dh-autoreconf dh-strip-nondeterminism dh-translations
  dialign dirmngr distro-info-data dmsetup dpkg dpkg-dev emboss emboss-data
  emboss-lib evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common
  evolution-data-server-online-accounts fakeroot fastjar fdisk
  fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-extra fonts-liberation2 g++ g++-7 gcc gcc-7
  gcc-7-base gcc-8-base geoclue-2.0 gfortran gfortran-7 gir1.2-atk-1.0
  gir1.2-goa-1.0 gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-harfbuzz-0.0
  gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 gir1.2-pango-1.0 gir1.2-snapd-1 gir1.2-vte-2.91
  gnome-desktop3-data gnupg gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gpg gpg-agent
  gpg-wks-client gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm gpgv gsettings-desktop-schemas
  gsettings-ubuntu-schemas gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gtk-update-icon-cache
  hplip-data icu-devtools ifupdown iio-sensor-proxy indicator-common
  indicator-datetime init-system-helpers intltool jarwrapper java-common
  java-wrappers jemboss jq libabw-0.1-1 libaccountsservice0
  libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl
  libapache-pom-java libapparmor-perl libapparmor1 libapt-inst2.0
  libapt-pkg-perl libapt-pkg5.0 libarchive-cpio-perl libargon2-0 libasan4
  libassuan0 libatinject-jsr330-api-java libatk-bridge2.0-0
  libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data
  libatomic1 libautodie-perl libbatik-java libbinutils libbiojava-java
  libbiojava1.7-java libblas-dev libblas3 libblkid1 libboost-date-time1.65.1
  libboost-filesystem1.65.1 libboost-iostreams1.65.1 libboost-locale1.65.1
  libboost-system1.65.1 libboost-thread1.65.1 libbytecode-java libbz2-1.0
  libbz2-dev libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dbg libc6-dev
  libcairo-gobject-perl libcairo-perl libcairo2 libcamel-1.2-61 libcc1-0
  libcdr-0.1-1 libcilkrts5 libclone-perl libclucene-contribs1v5
  libclucene-core1v5 libcmis-0.5-5v5 libcolord2 libcommons-collections3-java
  libcommons-compress-java libcommons-dbcp-java libcommons-io-java
  libcommons-jexl2-java libcommons-lang3-java libcommons-logging-java
  libcommons-net-java libcommons-parent-java libcommons-pool-java
  libcryptsetup12 libcurl4 libdata-dump-perl libdbus-1-3 libdevmapper1.02.1
  libdpkg-perl libdrm-common libdrm2 libe-book-0.1-1 libebackend-1.2-10
  libebook-1.2-19 libebook-contacts-1.2-2 libecal-1.2-19 libedata-book-1.2-25
  libedata-cal-1.2-28 libedataserver-1.2-23 libencode-locale-perl libeot0
  libepoxy0 libepubgen-0.1-1 libetonyek-0.1-1 libevdev2 libexporter-tiny-perl
  libfakeroot libfdisk1 libfile-fcntllock-perl libfile-listing-perl
  libfile-stripnondeterminism-perl libfile-which-perl libfont-afm-perl
  libfontconfig1 libfreehand-0.1-1 libfreetype6 libgadu3 libgail-3-0
  libgail-common libgail18 libgbm1 libgcc-7-dev libgcc1 libgcrypt20 libgdata22
  libgdbm-compat4 libgdbm5 libgeoclue-2-0 libgeocode-glib0 libgfortran-7-dev
  libgfortran4 libgif7 libgirepository-1.0-1 libglib-object-introspection-perl
  libglib-perl libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev-bin
  libgmime-3.0-0 libgmp10 libgnome-desktop-3-17 libgnutls30 libgoa-1.0-0b
  libgoa-1.0-common libgomp1 libgpg-error0 libgpgme11 libgpgmepp6
  libgraphite2-3 libgraphite2-dev libgrilo-0.3-0 libgssapi-krb5-2
  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 libgstreamer1.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin
  libgtk-3-common libgtk2-perl libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtk3-perl
  libguava-java libgupnp-igd-1.0-4 libgweather-3-15 libharfbuzz-dev
  libharfbuzz-gobject0 libharfbuzz-icu0 libharfbuzz0b libhogweed4
  libhpdf-2.3.0 libhsqldb-java libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl
  libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhtsjdk-java
  libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl
  libhttp-message-perl libhttp-negotiate-perl libhunspell-1.6-0 libibatis-java
  libical3 libicu-dev libicu-le-hb-dev libicu-le-hb0 libicu60 libiculx60
  libidn2-0 libinput-bin libinput10 libio-html-perl libio-pty-perl
  libio-socket-ssl-perl libip4tc0 libisl19 libitm1 libj2ssh-java
  libjack-jackd2-0 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libjaxp1.3-java libjpeg-dev
  libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg-turbo8-dev libjpeg8-dev libjq1 libjson-c3
  libjson-glib-1.0-0 libjson-glib-1.0-common libjsr305-java libk5crypto3
  libkeyutils1 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libksba8 liblapack-dev liblapack3
  liblcms2-2 liblirc-client0 liblircclient0 liblist-moreutils-perl
  liblocale-gettext-perl liblog4j1.2-java liblsan0 libltdl-dev libltdl7
  liblwp-mediatypes-perl liblwp-protocol-https-perl liblz4-1 liblzma-dev
  liblzma5 libmail-sendmail-perl libmount1 libmp3lame0 libmpc3 libmpdec2
  libmpfr6 libmpg123-0 libmpx2 libmspub-0.1-1 libmwaw-0.3-3 libmysqlclient20
  libncurses5 libncurses5-dev libncursesw5 libnet-dns-perl libnet-http-perl
  libnet-libidn-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libnettle6 libnghttp2-14 libngs-java
  libngs-sdk-dev libngs-sdk1 libnice10 libnpth0 libnspr4 libnss3 libnuma1
  libodfgen-0.1-1 libonig4 libopus0 liborc-0.4-0 liborcus-0.13-0 libp11-kit0
  libpackagekit-glib2-18 libpagemaker-0.0-0 libpango-1.0-0 libpango-perl
  libpango1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpangoxft-1.0-0
  libpcre16-3 libpcre3 libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 libperl5.26
  libperlio-gzip-perl libphonenumber7 libpicard-java libpng-dev libpng-tools
  libpng16-16 libpolkit-agent-1-0 libpolkit-gobject-1-0 libpoppler73
  libpostgresql-jdbc-java libpq5 libprotobuf-c1 libprotobuf10 libpsl5
  libpython3-stdlib libpython3.6-minimal libpython3.6-stdlib libquadmath0
  libreadline-dev libreadline7 libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc
  libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome
  libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-gtk2 libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-impress
  libreoffice-math libreoffice-pdfimport libreoffice-style-galaxy
  libreoffice-style-tango libreoffice-writer librevenge-0.0-0
  librhythmbox-core10 librtmp1 libseccomp2 libsecret-1-0 libselinux1
  libservlet3.1-java libsigsegv2 libsmartcols1 libsnapd-glib1 libsnappy-java
  libsnappy-jni libsnappy1v5 libsocket6-perl libsoup2.4-1 libssl1.1
  libstdc++-7-dev libstdc++6 libsub-identify-perl libsub-name-perl
  libsys-hostname-long-perl libsystemd0 libtasn1-6 libtext-charwidth-perl
  libtext-iconv-perl libtext-soundex-perl libthai0 libtinfo-dev libtinfo5
  libtool libtotem-plparser-common libtotem-plparser18 libtry-tiny-perl
  libtsan0 libtwolame0 libubsan0 libudev1 libunistring2 libuuid-perl
  libvisio-0.1-1 libvpx5 libvte-2.91-0 libvte-2.91-common libwacom-common
  libwacom2 libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0 libwayland-server0
  libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwebp6 libwebpdemux2 libwebpmux3
  libwebrtc-audio-processing1 libwhoopsie0 libwpd-0.10-10 libwpg-0.3-3
  libwps-0.4-4 libwww-perl libwww-robotrules-perl libxalan2-java
  libxerces2-java libxkbcommon0 libxml-commons-external-java
  libxml-commons-resolver1.1-java libxml-parser-perl
  libxmlgraphics-commons-java libxmlsec1 libxmlsec1-nss libxrandr2 libxz-java
  libyaml-0-2 libzstd1 locales m4 mount mysql-common ncurses-bin
  networkd-dispatcher onboard onboard-common openjdk-11-jre
  openjdk-11-jre-headless p11-kit-modules perl perl-base perl-modules-5.26
  perl-openssl-defaults pidgin-data pinentry-curses po-debconf primer3
  publicsuffix python-apt python-cairo python-debian python-gi python-gi-cairo
  python3 python3-apt python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
  python3-brlapi python3-cairo python3-crypto python3-cups python3-dbus
  python3-debconf python3-distro-info python3-distupgrade python3-distutils
  python3-gdbm python3-gi python3-gi-cairo python3-lib2to3 python3-lxml
  python3-markupsafe python3-minimal python3-pkg-resources python3-pycurl
  python3-scour python3-six python3-software-properties python3-update-manager
  python3-yaml python3.6 python3.6-minimal r-base-core r-base-dev r-cran-boot
  r-cran-class r-cran-cluster r-cran-codetools r-cran-foreign
  r-cran-kernsmooth r-cran-lattice r-cran-mass r-cran-matrix r-cran-mgcv
  r-cran-nlme r-cran-nnet r-cran-rpart r-cran-spatial r-cran-survival
  r-doc-html r-recommended rhythmbox-data scour software-properties-common
  software-properties-gtk systemd sysvinit-utils totem-common
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-core udev uno-libs3 update-manager-core
  update-notifier-common ure util-linux whoopsie zlib1g zlib1g-dev
Suggested packages:
  gnome-control-center apparmor-profiles-extra apparmor-utils apt-doc aptitude
  synaptic wajig autoconf-archive gnu-standards autoconf-doc binutils-doc
  devscripts cpp-doc gcc-7-locales debconf-doc debconf-utils
  libterm-readline-gnu-perl libnet-ldap-perl libqtgui4-perl libqtcore4-perl
  dh-make dwz default-java-plugin dbus-user-session pinentry-gnome3 tor
  debsig-verify debian-keyring emboss-doc emboss-test embassy clustalw
  evolution g++-multilib g++-7-multilib gcc-7-doc libstdc++6-7-dbg
  gcc-multilib flex bison gcc-doc gcc-7-multilib libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg
  libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg libasan4-dbg liblsan0-dbg libtsan0-dbg
  libubsan0-dbg libcilkrts5-dbg libmpx2-dbg libquadmath0-dbg gfortran-multilib
  gfortran-doc gfortran-7-multilib gfortran-7-doc libgfortran4-dbg
  libcoarrays-dev parcimonie xloadimage scdaemon rdnssd
  libatinject-jsr330-api-java-doc jython librhino-java java-virtual-machine
  libjgrapht-java libbiojava-java-doc liblapack-doc glibc-doc
  libfont-freetype-perl libcommons-collections3-java-doc
  libcommons-dbcp-java-doc libgeronimo-jta-1.1-spec-java
  libcommons-io-java-doc libcommons-jexl2-java-doc libcommons-lang3-java-doc
  libavalon-framework-java libcommons-logging-java-doc
  libexcalibur-logkit-java libcommons-net-java-doc git bzr rng-tools gdbm-l10n
  libglib2.0-doc gnutls-bin libgraphite2-utils grilo-plugins-0.3 krb5-doc
  krb5-user libgtk2-perl-doc libhsqldb-java-doc picard-tools icu-doc jackd2
  libjsr305-java-doc liblcms2-utils lirc liblog4j1.2-java-doc libmail-java
  libtool-doc libcrypt-ssleay-perl liblzma-doc ncurses-doc opus-tools
  readline-doc libreoffice-base ocl-icd-libopencl1 libreoffice-style
  libreoffice-evolution libreofficekit-data tango-icon-theme
  fonts-crosextra-caladea fonts-crosextra-carlito libreoffice-java-common
  libstdc++-7-doc automaken gcj-jdk libauthen-ntlm-perl libxalan2-java-doc
  libbsf-java libxsltc-java libxerces2-java-doc
  libxml-commons-resolver1.1-java-doc libxmlgraphics-commons-java-doc m4-doc
  nfs-common fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho fonts-wqy-microhei
  fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-indic pinentry-doc libmail-box-perl ncbi-epcr
  python-apt-dbg python-apt-doc python3-doc python3-tk python3-venv
  python3-apt-dbg python-crypto-doc python-dbus-doc python3-dbus-dbg
  python3-gdbm-dbg python3-lxml-dbg python-lxml-doc python3-setuptools
  libcurl4-gnutls-dev python-pycurl-doc python3-pycurl-dbg
  python3-launchpadlib python3.6-venv python3.6-doc ess r-doc-info r-doc-pdf
  r-mathlib r-base-html texlive-base texlive-latex-base
  texlive-generic-recommended texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-fonts-extra
  texlive-extra-utils texlive-latex-recommended texlive-latex-extra texinfo
  gir1.2-rsvg-2.0 systemd-container java5-runtime util-linux-locales
Recommended packages:
  ubuntu-touch-sounds packagekit python3-uno snapd libwacom-bin
  libcompress-zlib-perl python3-bs4 python3-html5lib
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  account-plugin-aim account-plugin-yahoo cheese gnome-contacts
  gnome-video-effects hplip libclucene-contribs1 libclucene-core1 libcurl3
  libhpmud0 libnss3-nssdb libperl5.18 libpurple0 libsane-hpaio libsnmp30
  libunity-webapps0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-common perl-modules printer-driver-hpcups
  printer-driver-postscript-hp python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat rhythmbox
  rhythmbox-mozilla rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune
  rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugins system-config-printer-gnome
  systemd-shim telepathy-haze totem totem-mozilla totem-plugins ubuntu-desktop
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk unity-webapps-common unity-webapps-service
  update-manager update-notifier webapp-container webbrowser-app xul-ext-unity
  xul-ext-websites-integration
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  adwaita-icon-theme artemis autoconf automake autopoint autotools-dev
  binfmt-support binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu build-essential
  bzip2-doc ca-certificates-java cdbs cpp-7 debhelper default-jre
  default-jre-headless dh-autoreconf dh-strip-nondeterminism dh-translations
  dialign dirmngr distro-info-data dpkg-dev emboss emboss-data emboss-lib
  fakeroot fastjar fdisk fonts-dejavu-extra fonts-liberation2 g++ g++-7 gcc-7
  gcc-7-base gcc-8-base geoclue-2.0 gfortran gfortran-7 gir1.2-harfbuzz-0.0
  gir1.2-snapd-1 gir1.2-vte-2.91 gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gpg gpg-agent
  gpg-wks-client gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm gtk-update-icon-cache
  icu-devtools iio-sensor-proxy indicator-common intltool jarwrapper
  java-common java-wrappers jemboss jq libabw-0.1-1 libalgorithm-diff-perl
  libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libapache-pom-java
  libapt-inst2.0 libapt-pkg5.0 libarchive-cpio-perl libargon2-0 libasan4
  libatinject-jsr330-api-java libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni
  libbatik-java libbinutils libbiojava-java libbiojava1.7-java libblas-dev
  libblas3 libboost-date-time1.65.1 libboost-filesystem1.65.1
  libboost-iostreams1.65.1 libboost-locale1.65.1 libboost-system1.65.1
  libboost-thread1.65.1 libbytecode-java libbz2-dev libcairo-gobject-perl
  libcamel-1.2-61 libcc1-0 libcdr-0.1-1 libcilkrts5 libclucene-contribs1v5
  libclucene-core1v5 libcmis-0.5-5v5 libcolord2 libcommons-collections3-java
  libcommons-compress-java libcommons-dbcp-java libcommons-io-java
  libcommons-jexl2-java libcommons-lang3-java libcommons-logging-java
  libcommons-net-java libcommons-parent-java libcommons-pool-java
  libcryptsetup12 libcurl4 libdata-dump-perl libdrm-common libe-book-0.1-1
  libebackend-1.2-10 libebook-1.2-19 libebook-contacts-1.2-2 libecal-1.2-19
  libedata-book-1.2-25 libedata-cal-1.2-28 libedataserver-1.2-23
  libencode-locale-perl libeot0 libepoxy0 libepubgen-0.1-1 libetonyek-0.1-1
  libevdev2 libexporter-tiny-perl libfakeroot libfdisk1 libfile-listing-perl
  libfile-stripnondeterminism-perl libfile-which-perl libfont-afm-perl
  libfreehand-0.1-1 libgadu3 libgcc-7-dev libgcrypt20 libgdata22
  libgdbm-compat4 libgdbm5 libgeoclue-2-0 libgeocode-glib0 libgfortran-7-dev
  libgfortran4 libgif7 libglib-object-introspection-perl libglib2.0-dev
  libglib2.0-dev-bin libgmime-3.0-0 libgnome-desktop-3-17 libgnutls30
  libgpgmepp6 libgraphite2-dev libgrilo-0.3-0 libgtk3-perl libguava-java
  libgweather-3-15 libharfbuzz-dev libharfbuzz-gobject0 libhogweed4
  libhpdf-2.3.0 libhsqldb-java libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl
  libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhtsjdk-java
  libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl
  libhttp-message-perl libhttp-negotiate-perl libhunspell-1.6-0 libibatis-java
  libical3 libicu-dev libicu-le-hb-dev libicu-le-hb0 libicu60 libiculx60
  libidn2-0 libinput-bin libinput10 libio-html-perl libip4tc0 libisl19
  libj2ssh-java libjaxp1.3-java libjpeg-dev libjpeg-turbo8-dev libjpeg8-dev
  libjq1 libjson-c3 libjsr305-java libksba8 liblapack-dev liblapack3
  liblirc-client0 liblog4j1.2-java liblsan0 libltdl-dev liblwp-mediatypes-perl
  liblwp-protocol-https-perl liblz4-1 liblzma-dev libmail-sendmail-perl
  libmp3lame0 libmpfr6 libmpg123-0 libmpx2 libmspub-0.1-1 libmwaw-0.3-3
  libmysqlclient20 libncurses5-dev libnet-http-perl libnettle6 libnghttp2-14
  libngs-java libngs-sdk-dev libngs-sdk1 libnpth0 libodfgen-0.1-1 libonig4
  libopus0 liborcus-0.13-0 libpackagekit-glib2-18 libpagemaker-0.0-0
  libpcre16-3 libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 libperl5.26
  libphonenumber7 libpicard-java libpng-dev libpng-tools libpng16-16
  libpoppler73 libpostgresql-jdbc-java libpq5 libprotobuf-c1 libprotobuf10
  libpsl5 libpython3.6-minimal libpython3.6-stdlib libreadline-dev
  libreadline7 libreoffice-gtk2 libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-style-galaxy
  libreoffice-style-tango librevenge-0.0-0 librhythmbox-core10 librtmp1
  libseccomp2 libservlet3.1-java libsigsegv2 libsmartcols1 libsnapd-glib1
  libsnappy-java libsnappy-jni libsnappy1v5 libssl1.1 libstdc++-7-dev
  libsys-hostname-long-perl libsystemd0 libtinfo-dev libtool
  libtotem-plparser-common libtry-tiny-perl libtwolame0 libubsan0
  libunistring2 libvisio-0.1-1 libvpx5 libvte-2.91-0 libvte-2.91-common
  libwebp6 libwebpdemux2 libwebpmux3 libwebrtc-audio-processing1
  libwpd-0.10-10 libwpg-0.3-3 libwps-0.4-4 libwww-perl libwww-robotrules-perl
  libxalan2-java libxerces2-java libxml-commons-external-java
  libxml-commons-resolver1.1-java libxml-parser-perl
  libxmlgraphics-commons-java libxmlsec1 libxmlsec1-nss libxz-java libyaml-0-2
  libzstd1 m4 mysql-common networkd-dispatcher onboard-common openjdk-11-jre
  openjdk-11-jre-headless perl-modules-5.26 perl-openssl-defaults pidgin-data
  pinentry-curses po-debconf primer3 publicsuffix python3-cups python3-debconf
  python3-distro-info python3-distutils python3-lib2to3 python3-scour
  python3-yaml python3.6 python3.6-minimal r-base-core r-base-dev r-cran-boot
  r-cran-class r-cran-cluster r-cran-codetools r-cran-foreign
  r-cran-kernsmooth r-cran-lattice r-cran-mass r-cran-matrix r-cran-mgcv
  r-cran-nlme r-cran-nnet r-cran-rpart r-cran-spatial r-cran-survival
  r-doc-html r-recommended scour systemd zlib1g-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  accountsservice apparmor apt apt-transport-https apt-utils aptdaemon
  bash-completion binutils bzip2 cpp dbus debconf dmsetup dpkg
  evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common
  evolution-data-server-online-accounts fontconfig-config gcc gir1.2-atk-1.0
  gir1.2-goa-1.0 gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0
  gir1.2-pango-1.0 gnome-desktop3-data gnupg gpgv gsettings-desktop-schemas
  gsettings-ubuntu-schemas gstreamer1.0-plugins-base hplip-data ifupdown
  indicator-datetime init-system-helpers libaccountsservice0 libapparmor-perl
  libapparmor1 libapt-pkg-perl libassuan0 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0
  libatk1.0-data libatomic1 libautodie-perl libblkid1 libbz2-1.0 libc-bin
  libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dbg libc6-dev libcairo-perl libcairo2 libclone-perl
  libdbus-1-3 libdevmapper1.02.1 libdpkg-perl libdrm2 libfile-fcntllock-perl
  libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libgail-3-0 libgail-common libgail18 libgbm1
  libgcc1 libgirepository-1.0-1 libglib-perl libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin
  libgmp10 libgoa-1.0-0b libgoa-1.0-common libgomp1 libgpg-error0 libgpgme11
  libgraphite2-3 libgssapi-krb5-2 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0
  libgstreamer1.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgtk2-perl
  libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgupnp-igd-1.0-4 libharfbuzz-icu0 libharfbuzz0b
  libio-pty-perl libio-socket-ssl-perl libitm1 libjack-jackd2-0
  libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjson-glib-1.0-0
  libjson-glib-1.0-common libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0
  liblcms2-2 liblircclient0 liblist-moreutils-perl liblocale-gettext-perl
  libltdl7 liblzma5 libmount1 libmpc3 libmpdec2 libncurses5 libncursesw5
  libnet-dns-perl libnet-libidn-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libnice10 libnspr4
  libnss3 libnuma1 liborc-0.4-0 libp11-kit0 libpango-1.0-0 libpango-perl
  libpango1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpangoxft-1.0-0
  libpcre3 libperlio-gzip-perl libpolkit-agent-1-0 libpolkit-gobject-1-0
  libpython3-stdlib libquadmath0 libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc
  libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome
  libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-pdfimport
  libreoffice-writer libsecret-1-0 libselinux1 libsocket6-perl libsoup2.4-1
  libstdc++6 libsub-identify-perl libsub-name-perl libtasn1-6
  libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl libtext-soundex-perl libthai0
  libtinfo5 libtotem-plparser18 libtsan0 libudev1 libuuid-perl libwacom-common
  libwacom2 libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0 libwayland-server0
  libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwhoopsie0 libxkbcommon0 libxrandr2 locales mount
  ncurses-bin onboard p11-kit-modules perl perl-base python-apt python-cairo
  python-debian python-gi python-gi-cairo python3 python3-apt
  python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python3-brlapi python3-cairo
  python3-crypto python3-dbus python3-distupgrade python3-gdbm python3-gi
  python3-gi-cairo python3-lxml python3-markupsafe python3-minimal
  python3-pkg-resources python3-pycurl python3-six python3-software-properties
  python3-update-manager rhythmbox-data software-properties-common
  software-properties-gtk sysvinit-utils totem-common
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-core udev uno-libs3 update-manager-core
  update-notifier-common ure util-linux whoopsie zlib1g
217 upgraded, 341 newly installed, 43 to remove and 1155 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/440 MB of archives.
After this operation, 1,291 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg-deb: error: archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/libc-bin_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb' has premature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc-bin_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb: error: archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/locales_2.27-3ubuntu1_all.deb' has premature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/locales_2.27-3ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb: error: archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb' has premature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb: error: archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/libgcc1_1%3a8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb' has premature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgcc1_1%3a8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-8-base_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb' has premature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-8-base_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc-bin_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/locales_2.27-3ubuntu1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgcc1_1%3a8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-8-base_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: You seem to have not updated Ubuntu 14.04 for a long time. Try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` first. Then `sudo apt-get autoremove`.

Answer (score 33):

Fix it by updating the `dpkg` package - It's a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/1730627) (fixed in `1.17.5ubuntu5.8`).

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dpkg
```

Afterwards, try again installing your desired package(s)

Comment: This worked perfectly to allow me to install [`sublime-text`](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html)! I was getting this error: `dpkg-deb: error: archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/sublime-text_3200_amd64.deb' has premature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up`, and your solution worked. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately `apt-get install dpkg` triggers this error so I am trapped...
`dpkg-deb: error: archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/libc-bin_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb' contains not understood data member control.tar.xz, giving up`

Comment: @wedi feel free to delete files under `/var/cache/apt/archives/`.  (Generally all /var/cache and ~/.cache are disposable.)

Comment: Installing dpkg worked for me!  This allowed me to get past installing Chrome inside a Selenium docker container.